# Text inserted to HTML disappears when function is done

Tags: javascript, html, json, object

I'm trying to store some data in JSON in localStorage, like this. (This is happening in a function.)

```
var inkomster = [];    
var nyInkomst = {
        "datum": datum,
        "beskrivning": beskrivning,
        "belopp": belopp
};
inkomster.push(nyInkomst);
localStorage.setItem("inkomster", JSON.stringify(inkomster));
```

At a later point it should be possible to retrieve the data and present it on a webpage, so I'm doing this in another function:

```
var retrievedIncomeObject = localStorage.getItem("inkomster");
storedInkomster = JSON.parse(retrievedIncomeObject);
var aktuellManadInkomster = {};

for (var key in storedInkomster) {
            if (storedInkomster.hasOwnProperty(key)) {  
                if(storedInkomster[key].datum.substring(3,5) == manadsnummer){
                aktuellManadInkomster[key] = storedInkomster[key];
                }
            }
}

for (var key2 in aktuellManadInkomster) { 
    if (aktuellManadInkomster.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
       document.getElementById('statistikDIV').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', aktuellManadInkomster[key2].datum);
    }
}
```

My data is presented in the statistikDIV tag as I want it, but only when the function is executing. ***When the function is done my data disappears from my webpage.***

I don't understand why this is happening, but my guess is that there is something about objects and scope in Javascript that I don't understand?

Comment: It could be that the entire page is reloading from the server, which could happen if you're invoking something from a "submit" button of a `<form>`.

Comment: You know that your data is stored as an object inside of an array and then when you extract it, you are trying to iterate the array (not the object in the array) with a `for/in` loop, right?

Comment: Yes, a button click in a form invokes the function that retrieves the data. So maybe that is my problem then.

Comment: I know I have objects inside of an array. I looked at it when I posted this question, but I don't think it affects the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added type="button" to my button tag. That solved the problem. Thanks!